# How to start, stop playing sound (ringtone) : Android

Tags: android, ringtone

I started playing sound by using: (Working)

```
RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(callerRing)).play();
```

And trying to stop playing sound using: (Not working)

```
ringtoneManager.stopPreviousRingtone();
```

Any help regarding this problem will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Ok. 
I got answer for my own question. So I want to share it with you guys.

1. Create instance of `Ringtone` as:

   ```
   Ringtone ringtone;
   ```
2. Get ringtone from `RingtoneManager` using `Uri`:

   ```
   ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, Uri.parse(ringtone_uri));
   ```
3. Start playing ringtone

   ```
   ringtone.play();
   ```
4. Stop playing ringtone

   ```
   ringtone.stop();
   ```

Thats all. 
Thank you